# I don't understand the last sentence in [dcl.fct.default]/3

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, declaration, default-arguments

[[dcl.fct.default]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#3) (emphasis is mine):

> A default argument shall be specified only in the
>   parameter-declaration-clause of a function declaration or
>   lambda-declarator or in a template-parameter (14.1); in the latter
>   case, the initializer-clause shall be an assignment-expression. A
>   default argument shall not be specified for a parameter pack. **If it
>   is specified in a parameter-declaration-clause, it shall not occur
>   within a declarator or abstract-declarator of a
>   parameter-declaration**.

The last sentence above says that if a default argument is specified in a parameter-declaration-clause, it shall **not** occur within a declarator or abstract-declarator, of a parameter-declaration. Nevertheless, when I look at the definition of parameter-declaration, I find the following in [[dcl.fct]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#3) (emphasis is mine):

> parameter-declaration:
>       attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq
>   declarator
>       attribute-specifier-seqopt
>   decl-specifier-seq declarator = **initializer-clause**
>       attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq
>   abstract-declaratoropt
>       attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq
>   abstract-declaratoropt = **initializer-clause**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a footnote in the Standard

> 102) This means that default arguments cannot appear, for example, in
>   declarations of pointers to functions, references to functions, or
>   typedef declarations

For example these declarations

```
void f(void g(int = 10));

void ( *pf )(int = 10);
```

are wrong.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.